# Excluding a property/field from fetching - Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, nsfetchrequest

How do you exclude a field from fetching? For example I have 3 Fields:

1. `username : String?`
2. `password : String?`
3. `capturedImages : NSSet?` of Images // I want to exclude this from fetching

I want to exclude `capturedImages` because it may contain huge amount images. If I just want  to fetch the `username` and `password`, How should I do that?

Comment: Did you try setPropertiesToFetch for your NSFetchRequest?

Comment: @Allen can you give me an example? I haven't tried it yet

Comment: @EncioPeter Something like "request.propertiesToFetch = ["Attribute A", "Attribute B"...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `capturedImages` is a relationship, those entities will not be prefetched (by default), but exist as part of [a fault in your object graph](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html).

Your images will not be retrieved until you specifically access the set's items.

On an unrelated note, you can modify your `NSManagedObject` subclass as follows, to make it easier to work with the object in Swift.

- Don't define an attribute as optional, if it is not optional in the model.
- Use the Swift `Set` type in place of `NSSet`.
- Strongly type the contents of a set.

  ```
  @NSManaged var username: String
  @NSManaged var password: String
  @NSManaged var capturedImages: Set<Image>
  ```

This eliminates unnecessary unwrapping or casting, as well as allowing Swift to type-check your code before it is compiled.